# Bootstrap4 dropdown only works in the second click

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I am working on a django project, that is using bootstrap4 and I'm with a little problem with dropdown toggler.

The toggler only toggles the dropdown-menu after the second link!

What I've done wrong?

This is my dropdown HTML code:

```
            <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown Toggler
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                 <a class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to  use the toggle like that and assign the `data-target` to the drop down menu with it's id

using

> > data-target="#navbarDropdown"

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
```

and then assign that id to the menu

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarDropdown" aria-controls="navbarDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
            <div id="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu"  role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 42):

I had the same problem then resolved. Often I due to a **double import** of bootstrap js libraries.
Hope will help you.

Comment: Yeah, this was also my issue. I used Mix extract vendor and I added the whole  boostrap.js there while only cherry picking  some js components in my entry point and laravel mix was getting confused.

Comment: proceeding with this answer by,

I am using a Template which loads its own JS

    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>

It also loaded bootstrap.js file, so had to remove previously added 

    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: This was my problem. I use Laravel, and the bootstrap js file is already exists in app.js.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue recently, i solved this issue by adding $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown() after loading the drop-down. Hope this may help without changing from the data-toggle="dropdown" to data-toggle="collapse".

Answer (score 3):

Try to put bootstrap js file before bootstrap css

Ex:

1. Link Bootstrap.min.js file first.

```html
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2. Then link css file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I got the same issue and after changing the positions of the js and css, dropdown works well. Hope it helped you.

Comment: normally  you shouldn't load your scripts in `<head>`, but I would refer you to [this comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/4770813) for a modern approach

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue recently, i solved it by writing custom script:

```
<div class="filter-dropdown text-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>



$(".filter-dropdown").on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("show");
    $(this).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
    $(this).next().addClass("show"); 
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it occurred because i imported bootstrap library twice. After removing one of them it worked well.
Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Iwan B. In Rails in javascripts I left only bootstrap.bundle.js. In Gemfile add gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.14.5', respectively in application.js we should add 
//= require popper

Answer (score 0):

add it to your js method

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

if you use Vue

```
@click.stop='yourMethod()'
```